# Website viewport and screen orientation, devices

Tags: html, css, viewport

I have a site with 980px width.
I need to adapt it to ipad, iphone, android chrome screens.
For ipad (1024x768) vertical screen i made a such:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=980, initial-scale=0.78, user-scalable=no">
```

But i need to make the same for horizontal orientation and mobiles.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bad practice. It would zoom in or out your viewport, not help in maintaining the same layout on different viewports. It is only possible with defining different mediqueries for differrent viewport. And you should also maintain your meta tag like this

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no,maximum-scale=1,width=device-width" />
```

Otherwise, you'll get some awful bugs in Android or iOs small devices.

Comment: what should i write in mediaqueries?